# xjc is failing with multiple xsd having different namespace

Tags: xml, xsd, xjc

I am struggling with an issue which might be very simlple but not ables to reason and analyze. I am using three different XSDs and then using that trying to generate java classes using XJC for web service creation purpose.

Prvilege.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="http://xmlns.hishekha.org/type"
    targetNamespace="http://xmlns.hishekha.org/type"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:element name="Privilege" type="Privilege" />

    <xs:complexType name="Privilege">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Id" type="xs:int" />
            <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Role.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="http://xmlns.hishekha.org/type"
    targetNamespace="http://xmlns.hishekha.org/type"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:privilege="http://xmlns.hishekha.org/type"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    attributeFormDefault="unqualified">

    <xs:import schemaLocation="Privilege.xsd" namespace="http://xmlns.hishekha.org/type"  />
    <xs:element name="Role" type="Role" />
    <xs:complexType name="Role">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Id" type="xs:int" />
            <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="Privilege" type="privilege:Privilege" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

User.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:u="http://xmlns.hishekha.org/type"
    targetNamespace="http://xmlns.hishekha.org/type" 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:role="http://xmlns.hishekha.org/type"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    attributeFormDefault="unqualified">

    <xs:include schemaLocation="Role.xsd"  />

    <xs:element name="User" type="u:User" />

    <xs:complexType name="User">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Id" type="xs:int" />
            <xs:element name="Username" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="FirstName" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="LastName" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="Email" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="Birthdate" type="xs:date" />
            <xs:element name="Role" type="role:Role" />
            <xs:element name="IsAccountExpired" type="xs:boolean" />
            <xs:element name="IsAccountLocked" type="xs:boolean" />
            <xs:element name="IsAccountASLExpired" type="xs:boolean" />
            <xs:element name="IsAccountEnabled" type="xs:boolean" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>       
</xs:schema>
```

Upto this point if I call mvn compile with following maven plugin comfig in pom.xml it genrates classes fine.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.5</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>xjc</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <clearOutputDir>false</clearOutputDir>
        <outputDirectory>src/main/java</outputDirectory>
        <schemaDirectory>src/main/webapp/schemas</schemaDirectory>
        <includes>**/*xsd</includes>
        <enableIntrospection>false</enableIntrospection>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

But as soon as I am trying to use this in the other xsd which has diffrent name space.

UserServiceOperations.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="http://xmlns.hishekha.org/services"
    targetNamespace="http://xmlns.hishekha.org/services"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:u="http://xmlns.hishekha.org/type"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    attributeFormDefault="unqualified">

    <xs:import namespace="http://xmlns.hishekha.org/type" schemaLocation="User.xsd" />

    <xs:element name="UserResponseOutput">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="User" type="u:User" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

(This I am doing for web service Input output schema) It starts throwing following errors

```
[INFO] Generating source...
[INFO] parsing a schema...
[ERROR] file:/C:/Users/hishekha.ORADEV/WorkspaceJ2EE/SimpleServices/src/main/web
app/schemas/UserServiceOperations.xsd[14,45]
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/C:/Users/hishekha.ORADEV/Workspac
eJ2EE/SimpleServices/src/main/webapp/schemas/UserServiceOperations.xsd; lineNumb
er: 14; columnNumber: 45; src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'u:User' to a(n)
'type definition' component.
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAX
ParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:198)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Err
orHandlerWrapper.java:134)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(
XMLErrorReporter.java:437)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.repo
rtSchemaErr(XSDHandler.java:4162)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.repo
rtSchemaError(XSDHandler.java:4145)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.getG
lobalDecl(XSDHandler.java:1741)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDElementTrave
rser.traverseNamedElement(XSDElementTraverser.java:405)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDElementTrave
rser.traverseLocal(XSDElementTraverser.java:194)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.trav
erseLocalElements(XSDHandler.java:3618)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.pars
eSchema(XSDHandler.java:633)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadSchema
(XMLSchemaLoader.java:616)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadGramma
r(XMLSchemaLoader.java:574)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadGramma
r(XMLSchemaLoader.java:540)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.validation.XMLSchemaFactory.n
ewSchema(XMLSchemaFactory.java:252)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.xmlschema.parser.SchemaConstraintChecker.che
ck(SchemaConstraintChecker.java:101) ....
```

I think I m doing some simple mistake but cant figure that out. please help guys.
Note: all xsd files are in the same directory.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in `UserServiceOperations.xsd`. It is importing the `User.xsd` schema correctly, and that is necessary to validate the reference to the qualified `User` element.

The problem is in `Role.xsd`. It belongs to the *same namespace* as `Privilege.xsd`, so you shouldn't be *importing* it, but *including* it (as you did in `User.xsd`, to include `Role.xsd`).

Not:

```
<xs:import schemaLocation="Privilege.xsd" namespace="http://xmlns.hishekha.org/type"  />
```

but

```
<xs:include schemaLocation="Privilege.xsd" />
```

If you change that one line, you can validate the `UserServiceOperations.xsd` and generate the classes with `xjc`.

Comment: Hi @helderdarocha, I tried that too but It's giving the same problem.

Comment: The change described fixes the schemas set. After that its likely to be a limitation/bug in xjc